# Possible to run C++ compiler from a Firebase Functions function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I was hoping to do something like this and run `g++` from within a function in Firebase Functions:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const { execSync } = require('child_process')

exports.gpp = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send(`g++ version: ${execSync('g++ -v')}`)
})
```

But Firebase tells me:

> /bin/sh: 1: g++: not found

So I tried `gcc`, `cc`, and `clang`. Are there any C++ compilers available or is there some other way I can compile a tiny piece of C++ code within a Firebase Function (aside from calling a function on my own server elsewhere)?

Answer (score 1):

The docker images that run your code in Cloud Functions don't provide any compilers.  You could possibly package your own and upload it with your code.  Or you could use Cloud Run and configure an image that contains the software you want.

Comment: I can package something like g++ with my Firebase Functions deployment? Do you know how I could do that? I'll check out Cloud Run, thank you.

Comment: I have no idea if it's possible or how.  It's very possible to package binaries for execution, but a compiler toolchain is a completely different matter.